# How to store multiple values for a single key in any Tree Data Structure?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, binary-search-tree, multimap

I know there is Data Structure called MultiMap which is a table like structure having O(n) linear searching time. I want to have a better searching time. Therefore, want to know if I can use a tree structure or it's variant (please suggest).

Edit:

Okay so, the MultiMap have O(log n) search and traversal according to the answers/documentations from its implementations.

1. But I had confusion why log n as, shown:
   [image]

as First, I have to go to nth element (the one I am looking for) then, I would enter its value (a list), will traverse the list and find the value, or simply retrieve the list itself (value) ?

2. Can anyone suggest, BST or B-Tree where I should I choose one over other to store my data from text file containing 10,000 of lines each line have a structure like  `123 3456 4567 5678 321` (and I have like more 10,000 lines like that ) to search for 321 when 123 is given and vice versa.

I thought B-Tree would be a good choice but I a not sure, and another thing, to search for 321, how I visualize was to store 123 as a key and 321 as its value ?

** There can be multiple `123 3456 4567 5678 989`, `123 3456 4567 5678 787` so that's why I assumed key with multiple values data structure should be helpful in this.

Comment: The complexity of a multimap is  Logarithmic in size. Do you mean that it will be linear in the case of having one key only and many values assigned to it?

Comment: And Lookup/Search complexity ? would it be logarithmic as well? Can you point  a implementation. As I assumed the Mulimap would be an array and each index contains a pointer to linked list which contains (multiple) values.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. The standard way to store multiple values for a single key is to put the multiple values in a structure, and store that structure as the value in the map. If you have some other meaning of "keys linked to multiple values," please edit your question and add an explanation.

Comment: Thanks, That was it I suppose to mean, single key with multiple values.  Which data structure would be best to store multiple values? As there is not always fixed number of values for  all keys, would a linked list be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

The search time complexity of a multimap is *Logarithmic* in size, not linear.

An implementation for example that achieves that is the C++ [`std::multimap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/multimap/), which offers a [`multimap::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/find/) method, which mentions:

> **Complexity**
>
> Logarithmic in size.

Answer (score 0):

A MultiMap implemented as a collection hash (that is, a hash of collection) has a **constant average search time**.

In C++ this implementation exists as [`unordered_multimap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_multimap/) (and the [complexity](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_multimap/find/) as noted).